# Mouseover in cypress

Tags: cypress, mouseover

I am a newbie in cypress and trying to create some basic scripts for my learning, Handling dropdown by clicking the elements is fine, but hovering on the element is not working in this case, I can see the required element is getting hovered but the sub-menu is not appearing.

```
it.only('Mouse hover using trigger ', () => {
        cy.visit('https://www.puregrips.com/pages/custom-grips')

        cy.contains("a", "Custom").trigger('mouseover')

    })
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) plugin and this worked with your webpage.

To install use the command:

```
npm i cypress-real-events
```

Then inside your `cypress/support/index.{js,ts}`, write:

```
import "cypress-real-events/support";
```

And in your code you can directly write:

```
cy.contains("a", "Custom").realHover('mouse')
```

[image: Test runner screenshot for the test]

**Note:** Since the above plugin uses Chrome DevTools Protocols to simulate native events, hence this will only work with Chromium-based browsers, so no firefox.

Things I tried that didn't work -

```
cy.contains("a", "Custom").trigger('mouseover')
cy.contains("a", "Custom").invoke('show')
```

Comment: Thanks, @alapan, it is working fine, and glad to learn this concept, but I am wondering why the trigger and invoke functions aren't working.

Comment: A simple explanation would be Cypress doesn't provide any out-of-the-box solutions for hovering, all the above things are simply workarounds. Now secondly how the hover is implemented in the webpage. The `.invoke('show')` method displays the elements which are hidden [ having the CSS property display:none], since the webpage didn't have this so it didn't work. And `.trigger('mouseover')` didn't work because the hovering is not done using javascript eventsin the webpage. You can learn more about it from here - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/hover

Comment: Can someone kindly confirm if the plugin still works.. I tried it today it passed without actually hovering in the element? Thank you

Comment: @ZombiePie, I just installed and used it, works for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can just try

```
cy.contains('a', 'Custom').trigger('mouseenter')
```

Comment: Thanks!  This worked for me and didn't require a 3rd party plugin. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just try this, it should work:

```
cy.get('.locater').invoke('show').click({ force: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cy.get('[your selector]')
        .eq(0).invoke('show')
        .trigger('mouseenter')
        .wait(1000)
        .should('have.attr','your-selector','Active tooltip')
        .trigger('mouseleave');
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for the above problem.

**Issue:**

Timed out retrying after 5000ms: cy.trigger() failed because this element is not visible: CUSTOM

This element <a.header__linklist-link.link--animated> is not visible because **its parent** <ul.header__linklist.list--unstyled.hidden-pocket.hidden-lap> has **CSS property: display: none**

```
    it.only("Mouse hover using trigger ", () => {
     cy.viewport(1440, 660); //setting viewport as site is responsive web design
     cy.visit("https://www.puregrips.com/pages/custom-grips"); //visit url
     //used within to get parent and children to get the desired web-element
     //and used invoke("show") to show the hidden elements
      cy.get(".header__linklist").within(() => { 
      cy.get("li").contains("CUSTOM").invoke("show");
});
});
```

Added final screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) worked for me but since the dropdown menu disappeared as Cypress found and tried to click on the item, I had to create an alias and force click on it:

```
cy.contains("Dropdown menu title").realHover("mouse");
cy.contains("Dropdown menu item").as("item");
cy.get("@item").click({ force: true });
```